# Sync client database to my own data base project every 06:00 AM in Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to make my own CRM project rest api backend LARAVEL 8 frontend Reactjs ,
So the client want all his data in the server to be transfer to my application every day at 06:00 AM so he can keep working on it ,

Can you guys propose an idea how to make it work thank you all ,

Comment: Take a look at scheduler and cron jobs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir , and how i am gonna make the sync between two databases should i make it on seeders or what exactly ?? @Aless55

Comment: No a seeder is mainly used for demo data, if the database structure is identical you can easily insert the data, otherwise you will have to transform the data according to your database.

Comment: So is like making a function that will be executed every day with scheduler that will insert the new lines in my data base  , should i connect them both in my project is it possible two connect more than two databases in laravel ?

Comment: Yes it is possible to set the connection for each model and even for certain calls individually. But if you are able to connect to this database why should you sync the recors? Can't you just work with the second connection?

Comment: it was just a proposition because i am not sure that clients would like to keep sharing there own database info for a long time si i must find just a soultion

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.